# Scala Play REST API test with external server

Tags: scala, rest, integration-testing, playback, web-api-testing

We have an API built with play/scala and writing sample end to end API tests. We don't want to start any embedded servers. At the moment, the application is started and an external test suite (written in a different javascript framework) makes requests and tests responses. We would like to convert these tests to scala tests but would like to keep the same process, i.e. no embedded servers but calling external REST endpoints. What is the best way to write these tests in scala? Any libraries recommended or samples that I can take a look at?

Comment: Yes to my best knowledge i can recommend you wiremock.
Have a look on this https://www.lewuathe.com/wiremock-in-scala.html

Comment: @AmitPrasad I'm not looking for any mocks here as I mentioned in the question. Real API would be up and running and we need to develop a scala test suite to fire requests and test responses.

Comment: [Cucumber](https://alexromanov.github.io/2016/07/15/cucumber-scala-sbt/) and/or Selenium could be what you're after if you're looking to test live applications.